# REST way to post several resources of the same type in one request

Tags: rest, web-services, http, url, endpoint

I'm designing REST API for performing CRUD operations on my entities.

I use the following URL for POST request that adds one permission:

```
POST: /permissions
```

This convention I have been using throughout all my end-points. However, now I need to be able to store a bunch of permissions via 1 request. It may contain 1-100 records. What URL modification shall I do to follow REST style and at the same time being able to use both end-points - add one or several permissions?

I thought about making only one end-point with a list of them, but it makes it confusing. Why should end user who uses my API send the JSON-array with only one element? I suppose they expect that we just want them to send object without array wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to define a new media-type and a new resource that holds the same data as many other resources.

A single piece of atomic data does not necessarily need to be only represented by a REST api at a single url. So one option might be to just create a new endpoint that can receive a resource which represents 'many permissions'.

One alternative might be to try to figure out why doing many HTTP requests is bad, and try to fix that problem without introducing a batch system. HTTP2 might help here, but introducing HTTP2 might not get you all the way there.

Comment: We use Tomcat 7.x that doesn't support HTTP2. Migration is tricky here. So, that is a good solution but not in this case...

Answer (score 2):

Yep! Arrays of things are fine, but that's just one nice batch hack when really HTTP/2 could do the job nicely.

When you "batch" you have to work out what to do if 1 in 100 fails. Revert the lot? That's gonna be confusing if your after save is firing off AMQP or other workers, can you call them back?

If you need to do 100 things, use HTTP/2 to do 100 things, then see which ones failed and retry the 1 that fails in 100, instead of trying to avoid "network chatter" which is designed for exactly this reason.